# scrollback <num> not working screen

Tags: linux, unix, gnu-screen

I use `screen` with putty and have configured scroll-back buffer to a large number but I'm unable to scroll up.

What I have tried already:

- As given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760346/how-do-i-increase-the-scrollback-buffer-in-a-running-screen-session) I tried setting `defscrollback 10000`
  in `.screenrc` but that doesn't seem to reflect a change.
- I have also tried exiting `putty`, closing all sessions of `screen`
  and starting things over again but it didn't help.
- setting `ctrl-a` then `:scrollback 10000` is not working either.

system specs:

```
uname -a
Linux amandeeg.desktop.amazon.com 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

lsb_release -ir    
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseClient 
Release:        5.4

screen --vewrsion
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
```

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359109/using-the-scrollwheel-in-gnu-screen#1125947 on how to enable scroll-backs using mouse wheel. short answer add `termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@` to your `.screenrc`

Answer (score 3):

Define “not working”. What are you doing to see that *it* does not work?

A hint: You have to change to **copy/scrollback mode** with <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then move the cursor or page up to see the historic lines in the scrollback buffer. They are **not in your terminal’s buffer**!